# Appcelerator iOS app: how to read Keychain value from Share Extension?

Tags: ios, swift, keychain, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I have a test Appcelerator iOS-only App (to simplify things). You can get the whole (really small app) in this [repo](https://github.com/dfreniche/TestKeychain)

This app stores a value in the Keychain from Appcelerator side, without problems, using [`Ti.Identity` module](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/titanium-identity). **The problem is that I can't read that value from Swift.**

Code to save something in the keychain, inside `alloy.js`:

```
var Identity = require('ti.identity');

// Create a keychain item
var keychainItem = Identity.createKeychainItem({
identifier: 'mypassword',
accessGroup: 'group.test.projects'
});


keychainItem.addEventListener('save', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info("Saved!!! ");

    keychainItem.addEventListener('read', function(e) {
            Ti.API.info("Read!!!");
            if (e.success) {
                Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(e, null, 4));
            } else {
                Ti.API.info("Error" + e);
            }
    });

    keychainItem.read();
});

// Write to the keychain
keychainItem.save('s3cr3t_p4$$w0rd');
```

This works, as after saving I print waht's inside the keychain with that key, and prints correctly `s3cr3t_p4$$w0rd`.

Now to read that from a Share Extension, I've added the extension to the project. Relevant parts of [`tiapp.xml`](https://github.com/dfreniche/TestKeychain/blob/master/tiapp.xml):

```
<ios>
...
<entitlements>
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
      <string>group.test.projects</string>
    </array>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
      <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)keychain.test.projects</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</entitlements>
<extensions>
  <extension projectPath="extensions/TestKeychain.xcodeproj">
    <target name="ShareExtension">
      <provisioning-profiles>
        <devices/>
      </provisioning-profiles>
    </target>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

App is is `<id>com.testapp</id>`

The entitlement file in the app extension is:

```
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>group.test.projects</string>
    </array>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)keychain.test.projects</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

To read it from Swift I've tried to:

```
let domain = "group.test.projects"
let login = "mypassword"
let keychainQuery: [NSString: NSObject] = [
    kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
    kSecAttrAccount: login as NSObject,
    kSecAttrService: domain as NSObject,
    kSecReturnData: kCFBooleanTrue,
    kSecMatchLimit: kSecMatchLimitOne]
var rawResult: AnyObject?
let keychain_get_status: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(keychainQuery as CFDictionary, &rawResult)

self.textView.text = "Reading something"

if (keychain_get_status == errSecSuccess) {
    if let retrievedData = rawResult as? Data,
        let password = String(data: retrievedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        // "password" contains the password string now
    }
} else {
    self.textView.text = "Error"
}
```

Also I've used this [Keychain Wrapper](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/titanium-identity/tree/master/ios/Classes/KeychainItemWrapper) from Ti.Identity. Without success. I always get `-25300,    /* The specified item could not be found in the keychain. */`

What's wrong in the Swift side of things?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a complete answer as your question is quite long, but there's an [example app that claims to do this](https://github.com/Cyber-Duck/ti-fingerprint-identity-boilerplate/tree/515f725d7afd3e9052750eac6cfd37e5aeea4f4f/app).

[Here's his example](https://github.com/Cyber-Duck/ti-fingerprint-identity-boilerplate/blob/515f725d7afd3e9052750eac6cfd37e5aeea4f4f/app/lib/fingerprint-identity.js).